# Hints for safe passwords that are easy to remember

Tags: passwords, password-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is your way to create good passwords that can actually be remembered?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/662/what-is-your-way-to-create-good-passwords-that-can-actually-be-remembered)

What are good hints to create passwords that are both safe and comfortable? By comfortable I mean e.g. not 40 chars of length.