# Do I need TFA if I have a strong password?

Tags: authentication, multi-factor, google

This is the inverse of this [question here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/49521/does-two-factor-authentication-reduce-the-need-for-a-long-password).

Google keeps prompting me to enable Two-Factor Authentication for my Google account. I don't like the inconvenience of TFA, such as mandating that I will always have my mobile device handy on me. Assuming that I have a secure (i.e. reasonably long and complex) password that isn't likely to cracked by the most high-end consumer hardware for at least the next decade, can I get away with keeping TFA off?

Comment: Define "get away with" - that seems like a risk assessment that only you can perform. I personally use strong passwords and 2FA because the risks I have assessed outweigh the inconvenience.

Comment: Are you aware of the threats that 2FA is meant to mitigate?

Comment: @nobody It does. Once again searching before posting the question failed to turn this up, thanks.

Comment: To be fair, the site's search functionality is mostly crap.