# Should cookies expire?

Tags: cookies

Let's say I have an account on a blog. I'm using https on every single page of that blog through web server rules, so there is no way to visit the page in the clear text. I'm also using a laptop that utilizes full disk encryption, and I'm the one who uses the machine. More over, I have 128 bit auto generated passwords for each site on the internet, and each of the password is different. I also store the passwords in an encrypted keyring, just in case that I need them, but usually I don't because of the cookies. And here's the problem. Most of the internet sites (especially WordPress ones) have strange policy regarding cookies. In the case of WordPress, the default cookie expiration time is set to 2 days. If you checked the "Remember" option, that would be 14 days. So once for a while you have to log in whether you like it or not.

Is this necessary? I mean, what would happen if the cookies have no expiration time set? Is there a way to steal them somehow? If you have the whole site encrypted, and no one can access your machine, should you still be worried about cookies that are sent through the internet? I've never been asked, for instance, by google for password while checking my emails.

Comment: Do some searches for "cookie stealing" and take a look at the old attack "firesheep". Just remember the difference between "session timeout" and "cookie expiry".

Comment: Does the "cookie stealing" work with a full https website?

Comment: Related: [How does changing your password every 90 days increase security?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/4704/29865)

Comment: I'm using 32-character passwords (128bit, randomly generated), and I've never had any issues with cracking the passwords. They stay the same for a really long time that can be measured in months, even years, and I've never had unauthorized access to my accounts. I think I'm different. :]

Answer (score 4):

First off, your connection to a website being encrypted does not necessarily mean that your connection is actually secure. It certainly helps, but encryption can differ massively in quality. You might have heard about [POODLE](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1232123), as well as [FREAK](https://freakattack.com/). Bugs and side effects like these could mean that a sufficiently powerful attacker might be able to break the SSL. And that's not even including the possibility that a CA has been compromised, like happened with [Diginotar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DigiNotar). And of course, the website itself might be compromised, with a piece of Javascript stealing your cookies and even your credentials, like [the Tunisian government did with Facebook](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/01/25/tunisia_facebook_password_slurping/).

So assume that the attacker has your cookie. The server actually uses that cookie to know who you are, because that's the only way it can know that. IP addresses can change and aren't unique enough. Browser sniffing is complicated and can break when you do something like patching Chrome (maybe to deal with a bug in TLS). hardware footprints are hard to acquire and aren't unique enough as well. So the only way is by having a small file on your computer that tells the server who you are. So if anyone knows what is in that file, they can use that to login as you.

You can test that yourself. Open your dev console, find your cookies list on this website, open an incognito tab to this website and edit the cookies using an extension. Once you refresh the page, you're logged in to the website without entering your credentials. A few years ago, there was a tool called Firesheep that could track non-TLS connections other people made on a public wifi (say, a starbucks) and impersonate them. Even now, you can buy a special tool called a Pineapple for 100 EUR, trick people into connecting to your wifi and steal their data.

Comment: This also has the same impact when it comes to, let's say, passwords in a login form, right? So if you have bugged ssl/tls, the password can be compromised. If the site isn't trusted, so passwords aren't secure either. When some webpage doesn't use full https, just log you in in that way, yes, you have cookie problem here, but I asked in the light of full implementation of ssl/tls protocol, so no matter what page you visit on a blog, it will always be encrypted, even if there's just a text.

Comment: @MikhailMorfikov The difference is that a password is only sent 1 time, to authenticate. The cookie is sent every time you make a connection to a website, even for something like a resource. So if you connect to a website via a network that's capable of MitM'ing you through something like a fake certificate or a bug in SSL, it can still take that cookie, since it can decrypt it.

Comment: Yes he can, but he can also take the password when a user would log in using the same network and the same bugged client/server software. I don't see any difference between the two, even when you send the password just once, and the cookies with every single request -- I think, they should set 2-day expiration period for passwords. :)

Comment: @MikhailMorfikov Consider a user on a mobile device, say a laptop or a smartphone. now, this user doesn't enter his passwords on public wifi because he knows the danger, so he enters it at home. The cookie can still be stolen though, which is effectively just as good as the password. In addition, a number of websites have a HTTPS login page, but then don't use TLS once the user is logged in afterwards, which means the cookie is transmit in cleartext (although this isn't the case for websites that implement TLS across the board).

Comment: I'm aware of not fully encrypted websites, but I explicitly asked about the ones that have ssl/tls fully implemented and the entire website is encrypted. I don't get the "entering password at home" feature -- if you're afraid of entering password, why should you use cookies in such a place? The main question is about the cookie expiration time -- does this have any sense when you visit fully encrypted website? Can you steal that cookie somewhat?

Comment: @MikhailMorfikov Yes, you can steal a cookie from a fully TLS'd website, mainly through MitM methods that exploit vulnerabilities in either the website itself or the TLS implementation. Nothing is perfectly safe.

Comment: So you can also get the password in that way. So I don't understand why they set 2 day expiration period only for cookies. :)

Comment: @MikhailMorfikov Users don't always enter their password on a page. They do, however, always send their cookies. It also depends on the website. Generally, it's financially important websites that do this.

Comment: I think google is very important today and it doesn't do that when I check my emails. Have you seen the google cookies? 2017 or 2024. :)

Comment: @MikhailMorfikov Google has their entire website on TLS and isn't vulnerable to the Poodle attack. They also have other defense mechanisms in place to safeguard their users. For example, someone logging in from Russia all of a sudden while they were in France 2 minutes ago, or requiring users to login again for sensitive changes like security data. If your website handles security just as well as Google does, then you can feel free to put long-duration cookies in. But if you are so secure, you probably woulnd't be asking this.

Comment: These arguments don't seem very strong. If an attacker can steal a cookie over a connection protected by TLS, I see no reason why they wouldn't also be able to figure out how to use that cookie before it expires in 2 days / 1 week / whatever. Also, seems to me they'd just as easily be able to steal your password. (Force a logout, then when the user logs back in steal their password, or just hijack the connection entirely and point it to a phishing page.) In any case, TLS should make this infeasible. If for some reason it doesn't though, cookie expiration certainly won't save you.

Comment: Wordpress has a feature to invalidate all cookies when you change the keys/salts. So if there was an issue with the server security, or some bugs in ssl/tls, you can simply invalidate all the cookies after you fix the problems. In that case, all people on you blog will have to log in again. I don't see any reason to log every 2 or 14 days especially when you use ssl/tls everywhere.

Comment: @MikhailMorfikov You mention Google and Wordpress. Both these companies have spent years investing in their security and developing fixes for their products. As I mentioned, if you can confidently say that your website is equally as secure as Google and Wordpress, then you can base your security features on their examples. But the vast majority of websites that are developed these days aren't as secure and thus can't rely on short-term cookies.