# Why do password creation/login screens hide the typed password?

Tags: passwords

I realize that the concept behind obscuring a password on a screen is to prevent someone "shoulder surfing" behind a user and seeing the typed in password. As a fairly good typist I have no problems with dealing with this, but this causes a lot of pain for people I know who are very slow typists: [(Dilbert strip) [image: my keyboard is broken]](http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-09-06)

Can't we just assume that people entering a password are checking to see if anyone is trying to look at their screen before they enter a password? Or is there some other reason for obscuring a screen password?

Comment: It's worth noting that password fields recently have started providing a "preview" button, typically in the field itself, which shows the password as plain text.

Comment: "C'mon guys, let's all gather around the computer and look at this presentation, but let me log in first so could you please all turn around?"

Comment: @iAdjunct: I agree the presentation issue is a problem. On the other hand, it requires a technically clueless presenter (unable to turn off the display). How often could that possibly happen in modern corporate....I withdraw my objection.

Comment: @MarkRipley even with a reasonably technically competent presenter, the delay in turning off the display, waiting for the resolution to adjust, turning it back on, and waiting for the resolution again can really kill the momentum of a presentation - particularly when you have to log in multiple times within one presentation (e.g. logging into multiple different internal tools - a regular occurence where I work.)

Comment: There are also times such as in large public presentations where 'turning off the display' in front of crowds of people is not possible or just undesirable.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate? Odd. I fail to see how typing speed is remotely relevant to having to remember what characters you've already typed, could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Wouldn't this increase the attack surface by placing a plaintext version of the password on the RAM?  Then an attacker only needs to access the program memory and he can scrape off the password.  Most of the current answers focus on screen capture as the only way to get a displayed password through software.

Comment: [@CodyP](http://security.stackexchange.com/users/109672/cody-p) the plaintext version of the password will exist in-memory in either case. The question specifically focuses on the visual aspect.

Comment: @MarkRipley Not all presentations to groups are done on a projector. I frequently have people gather around my computer where I proceed to log in, then log into another computer in a terminal thereby typing in my password multiple times. It would not be reasonable to ask the program director to put on a blindfold several times before I show him a single chart with an important number.

Comment: @iAdjunct: I must say that in at least 9998 out of 10000 cases, nobody is looking over my shoulder. Especially when coaxing a password into my phone, it just sucks when I can't see the password.

Comment: I'm not sure why I can't post an answer.

But if you want something like that for Usability point of view Go for it, it's already implemented on different locations with f/e the Windows 8 (I didn't try 10) login screen. Most of the time there is an option to TOGGLE the masking. This way you can prevent people around you from sneaking a peak but if you're confident this wont happen  you can reveal the password.

Comment: If the password is visible by default people will only notice after they have typed in their password and everyone saw it. So it must be default-invisible.

Comment: @phresnel - I must say that 500 out of 1000 cases there is somebody right there. Don't make the mistake of over-generalizing your specific case. There are plenty of people in positions where that really, really matters - and it gets worse when you get into classified environments.

Comment: A couple of days ago I went through a long password recovery process where I failed all the security questions and had to use other means to reset my password.  When I finally got logged in and started writing a message it turned out my keyboard map was wrong.  Up to that point everything I typed was hidden.  Now I'm not even sure what my new password is.  It's certainly not an ideal system.

Comment: I unfortunately cannot add an Answer due to lack of Karma, but the Nielsen Norman Group (usability studies) recommended against Password Masking in 2009: https://www.nngroup.com/articles/stop-password-masking/ . Can't say I agree with their findings.

Comment: if you are sharing your screen with audience, you can type your password without thinking twice.

Comment: @iAdjunct: Likewise, don't over-generalize your case. It was just my example. As indicated by use of "my" and "I". It also fits my wife and the rest of my family. Even at work, nobody's looking over my shoulder, if am at all at the office. But yes, your case and my case are specific cases. Just saying that non-hidden passwords would be more optimal for me.

Comment: @Techmaster: True. But if you don't do that and type asterisk passwords, you have to thing thrice in order to not exhaust your tries. I mean, I like to not overcomplicate computer usage because of security issues that simply don't apply to me. The default should be the safe variant, but non-hidden passwords are not bad for everyone.

Comment: @phresnel Making that controllable (whether or not to display the password) requires a control and screen real-estate and it clutters up the interface, so that control is often not optimal. The default in any case has to be to hide it: the loss due to having it hidden for somebody who wants it visible is annoyance; the loss due to having it visible for somebody who wants it hidden could mean compromising your entire user account.

Comment: @iAdjunct: The screen real estate is about this, with asterisks being password characters: **********$. '$' is the toggle to unhide the password. You share one password character in exchange for a toggle. Pretty constructed argument. I am thankful most of the phone apps I use do make use of this huge amount of screen real estate. Why do you think it clutters the interface? And a control? Yes, apps have tens, if not hundreds of them. Do you really think that is a relevant argument? If so, please elaborate.

Answer (score 37):

The primary protection provided by password masking is against shoulder surfing, as you suggest. Typing speeds are a factor, but a reality is that screens could be captured by video recording devices as well (which exposes passwords to typed on mobile phones, where each character is visible for a few hundred milliseconds before being masked). As the exact environment around a user is not known, it makes sense to have a default masked view, with an option to preview as suggested by  [@William Mariager](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/86602/william-mariager). This is also true in case of shared screens, projectors... Some simplistic malicious software do perform periodic image/video screengrabs, which is also defended by password masking.

Hence we can't assume that people can always check to see if their screen is obscured.

But, another reason for doing this now is historical-- users are now so used to seeing masked passwords that websites using unmasked passwords are perceived to be insecure
([Source](http://passwordmasking.com/)). The masking also informs **all** users that the information being entered is sensitive.

Also read: [Schneier about password masking](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/07/the_pros_and_co.html)

Studies that argue against password masking: [[1](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/stop-password-masking/)][[2](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Password-Visualization-beyond-Password-Masking-Gruschka-Iacono/c74f4795e6b434dd9c32595470a2b3d641704699/pdf)]

Comment: I like your links about this. The "historical argument" for password obscuring reminds me of the question here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4704/how-does-changing-your-password-every-90-days-increase-security?lq=1 where one conclusion was that forced password changes every 90 days is partially caused by regulators clueless about security.

Comment: Personally I think the "typed-char-being-visible-for-a-split-second" feature (which seems to be popular with Mac devices) is actually horrible. I have seen several (recorded) live presentations where the presenter inadvertently published one of their passwords that way.

Comment: @Jedi My assumption is that it is due to the lack of tactile feedback when using an on-screen keyboard, meaning you're more likely to hit the wrong button by accident and not realize it until you've typed out the whole password and it fails to validate. That's been my experience, at least; on physical keyboards, I only have issues when I type too fast, while I have a much higher rate of typos on touchscreens due to the lack of tactile feedback.

Comment: @JAB: Certainly some feedback is needed when characters are typed, but how about having a blob appear bigger or brighter and then shrink down to the size of the "normal" password dots?

Comment: @supercat The issue isn't getting the number of characters wrong (terminal password input doesn't even display placeholders in most cases, so that's sometimes seen as even less of an issue for physical keyboards [though it makes it a pain when you know you messed up but didn't keep track of how many characters you've entered and thus have to hit backspace extra times just to be sure you cleared it]) but the likelihood of pressing the wrong character.

Comment: @fgysin I've never seen that on OS X, but I have seen it on Apple and Android mobile devices where I presume it's a feature to help people know if they miss-tapped the screen and I know iOS at least was also mirroring that to projectors.

Comment: I wouldn't say screen grabbing malware is always simplisitic.  HTML5 opened up the opportunity for screen capture and sharing which can even allow cross-origin screen capture.  Although I'm not sure this is being exploited in the wild.  See http://www.ieee-security.org/TC/SP2014/papers/AllYourScreensareBelongtoUs_c_AttacksExploitingtheHTML5ScreenSharingAPI.pdf

Comment: It's amusing how people perceive this as secure when all it takes to uncover the password you just entered is to change the "type" of the input field from "password" to "text".

Comment: @Gigala That's true but, at least on Windows, you could easily write a simple program that stays in the background, loops over all open windows and all open controls and does a getText on the text boxes. If a text box is "text" it will return the content, but if it is "password" it will return an empty string. To change the type from "password" to "text" a specific user action is necessary. But honestly, if you want some random user's password just ask him/her. There's a good chance he/she will just tell you.

Comment: I agree with the idea that (my addendum: *stupid*) users see ****** fields as more secure. I once had an entirely personal-use website, no legitimate concerns about other people seeing your password, and received at least 2 complaints I was trying to steal people's passwords because it displayed the text instead of *****. Which of course told me that if I *was* to steal their password, it'd probably work on other sites, else they wouldn't care if I, the system admin, had it.

Answer (score 21):

> Can't we just assume that people entering a password are checking to see if anyone is trying to look at their screen before they enter a password?

In [May 2008 Schneier cited](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2008/05/spying_on_compu.html) a research paper [Compromising Reflections or How to Read LCD Monitors Around the Corner](http://gauss.ececs.uc.edu/Courses/c653/extra/reflections.pdf) claiming:

> All it took was a $500 telescope trained on a reflective object in front of the monitor. For example, a teapot yielded readable images of 12 point Word documents from a distance of 5 meters (16 feet). From 10 meters, they were able to read 18 point fonts. With a $27,500 Dobson telescope, they could get the same quality of images at 30 meters.

8 years later, with both camera resolution and screen quality increased, you cannot assume any environment to be safe just because there is no human present.

Comment: This information is impressive. And the same methods can't see which letters a user types on his keyboard because?

Comment: ...because screen emits light which reflects from objects more easily than light already reflected from keyboard?

Comment: I don't disagree with your answer, it's just that if someone can see (using appropriate telescopes and reflecting objects) your screen, I don't think that seeing your keyboard (and what you are typing) is much more difficult. If that is the level of attack we need to defend against, I see a future for "keyboard tents" to obscure what we type when we enter passwords. Or just stop using passwords alone as an authentication system.

Comment: In my opinion it is orders of magnitude more difficult. If someone looks at the computer screen wearing glasses with reflective coating you can see a screen reflection with a naked eye. You won't see their keyboard reflection.

Comment: A very valid point. I suspect this means that we all need to block our windows against visible light to prevent this sort of attack, reducing all paranoid people to their normal pasty white color. The attackers will then be forced to hide cheap, incredibly small cameras that you can buy on-line where they will point directly at our screens or keyboards. What I am trying to get at is that if you just keep adding every security measure you can think of without considering its impact you just end up with an unworkable system. "Let's turn off video subsystem while the password is entered! Secure!"

Comment: For completeness, found the [source](http://gauss.ececs.uc.edu/Courses/c653/extra/reflections.pdf). I suppose apart from telescopes observing screens, you would also worry about [acoustic sniffing](http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/publications/thesis/online/IM100855.pdf) or [smartphone motion-based attacks](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/hotsec11/tech/final_files/Cai.pdf). Which brings you full circle to OP's POV- `stop using passwords alone as an authentication system`

Comment: Here are a couple more sources.  It's possible to capture images off of the eye itself and things like plastic soda bottles. https://www.infsec.cs.uni-saarland.de/projects/reflections/  http://www.mia.uni-saarland.de/Publications/backes-sp09.pdf

Comment: @MarkRipley just buy http://www.bhphotovideo.com/bnh/controller/home?O=&sku=253370&gclid=CMHOvOq6is0CFQcfhgodIswNZw&is=REG&ap=y&m=Y&c3api=1876%2C92051677562%2C&A=details&Q= it is a bag photographers use to handle film outside without a dark room.  Put your laptop in the black bag and type the password.  Do note the people around you can observe your shoulder muscles and make inferences about which keys you are pressing.  Better just get a photographic dark room.

Answer (score 6):

> Can't we just assume that people entering a password are checking to see if anyone is trying to look at their screen before they enter a password?

It's not that simple, for a number of reasons.

You might be in a public location, where there are too many other people around for you to monitor. Don't forget that you don't have eyes in the back of your head.

You might be in the presence of people you don't trust, but for social reasons you do not want to, or are not supposed to, act outwardly distrustful (such as covering the screen with your hand, or asking them to turn around). They might even be close friends, family, or co-workers, or people you're in a conversation with. It's not always convenient to relocate yourself.

You might be in the presence of people with good vision and memory, who might accidentally see parts of your password.

So no, you might not notice everyone who might look at your screen. No, you might not know if they're looking or not. No, you might not be in a social position to stop them from looking. And no, it's not only the "bad actors" you need to worry about—anyone could mistakenly catch a glimpse. So it's convenient for the default to be safe against shoulder surfing. It can be nice when a program gives you the option to display the password visually, but all features take work to implement. It's important to have, at a minimum, the mode where the password is invisible. And it's better to have that as the default.

Comment: `people with good vision and memory` yep... try to *intentionally* forget something and see how easy that is to do.