# Requiring regular password change counterproductive

Tags: password-policy

According to

http://www.csoonline.com/article/3195181/data-protection/vendors-approve-of-nist-password-draft.html

> "There have been multiple studies that have shown requiring frequent
>   password changes to actually be counterproductive to good password
>   security..."

I would like to see some of these studies and would appreciate references.

Comment: Per would likely have studies: https://blog.keepersecurity.com/2016/11/16/keeper-qa-password-tips-with-passwordscon-founder-per-thorsheim/ I'll try to dig some out.

Comment: Most of the time when I ask people in the office whether their passwords are ending with an increasing number, they are maintaining a guilty silence. Of course it is good to have official studies, but you can also just look around.

Comment: Thomas, you'll find links to the only studies on password expiration, that I'm aware of, in the 'possible duplicate' linked answers.  There are also a few less formal studies like https://isc.sans.org/forums/diary/Password+History+Insights+Shared+by+a+Reader/22278/

Answer (score 0):

There was a healthy debate a couple of years back here, I hope it's stickied.  Lets see:  [How does changing your password every 90 days increase security?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4704/how-does-changing-your-password-every-90-days-increase-security) was where we had this.

The NIST itself gathers feedback from industry, government agencies (most specifically: the intelligence community) and provides guidelines to government as to how to secure their systems against nations stealing them.  I realize that's an appeal to authority and not a reference, but hopefully it helps provide context for the NIST.