# Is it secure to set the encryption password the same as the root password?

Tags: passwords, linux, disk-encryption

When installing Manjaro Linux, it shows the following screen:

[image]

What's the logic behind that?

Comment: There are different attacks on the LUKS password and the root password. By using the same password for both of them you open both up to all possible attacks on each of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/166541

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Same password for full disk encryption, user account, admin account](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/166541/same-password-for-full-disk-encryption-user-account-admin-account)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'll post as an answer.

In general terms, you should never use the same password twice.
Manjaro is only enforcing and trying to make it mandatory.

Maybe [this answer here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/166541/same-password-for-full-disk-encryption-user-account-admin-account) can give you a better overview.